# JSON parsing error shows syntax error

Tags: json

I am getting this json from server:

```
{"cust":[{"email":"harsht283raj@tyu.com","url":"www.uzti.com"},
        {"email":"harshit.raj@tyu.com","url":"www.url.com"}]}
```

I have checked this json on JsonLint site and it shows valid json.
 But I have retrieve the elements by Javascript. When I do this JSON.parse(json), I get the following error:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 9 of the JSON data.
Even if I directly use jaon.cust, it shows undefined
How do I Resolve this?

Comment: if you do `console.log(json)` right before the `JSON.parse(json)`, do you get the exact same result as the json data you pasted here?

Comment: yes, I get the exact same result

Comment: What length of response from server?

Comment: did not understand what you meant, but server took 600ms or did you ask something else?

Comment: console.log(jsonStringFromServer.length)

Comment: are you getting json from server or json formated string?

Comment: and show us the code how you are accessing it, it will be helpful for us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.parse()` parses string to json, if you are getting direct JSON from server then you have no need to parse it , access it directly with property, for example, look at the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var a = {"cust":[{"email":"harsht283raj@tyu.com","url":"www.uzti.com"},
        {"email":"harshit.raj@tyu.com","url":"www.url.com"}]} ;
        
alert(a.cust[0].email);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that JSON.parse should use with a string not with a json object.

```
JSON.parse('{"cust":[{"email":"harsht283raj@tyu.com","url":"www.uzti.com"},{"email":"harshit.raj@tyu.com","url":"www.url.com"}]}')
```

try to convert your json to a string and use parse function.